# Sync list of custom words in spell checker

Tags: firefox, android, spell-checking

Is there a way to sync the list of custom words I added to the spell checking dictionary of firefox?

I would like to sync this list to a different pc.

It would be even better if I could sync this to my android swype app.

Is there a tool for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Firefox this is easy enough as your customised spelling words are stored in a plaintext file called `persdict.dat`. The full path will vary according to the filename used for the specific subdirectory, it will be something like `$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/` using a *wildcard* for the random letters and numbers; but this screenshot will give you the idea:

[image]

Simply copy this file to another profile, in the appropriate location, for the custom dictionary to be reused. If you would like you can also manually add words to this file using your favorite text editor.

For Swype I believe there is no easy way unfortunately. The contents of the file `persdict.dat` can be read with a text editor and then *manually* entered into Swype:

1. Type a word that is not in your dictionary (for instance, “Ubuntu”)
2. Tap on your word in the Word Choice List
3. Tap on the prompt that then appears to add your word

This word 'Ubuntu' is now added to your personal dictionary, a painfully manual process but effective nevertheless...

**References:**

- [MozillaZine: Dictionaries - Personal Dictionaries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dictionaries#Personal_dictionary)
- [Swype ios tips...](http://www.swype.com/product-features/ios/tips.html)